# SM 03 Diode Identification

Tags: diodes, identification, surface-mount

I'm trying to replace a bad diode in my Chevrolet Captiva C100 rear wiper motor circuit board.

The marking on the SMD diode says SM 03 and I could not cross reference the marking with the correct type of replacement diode.

The good diode has forward voltage around 0.632V and its physical dimensions are 4.0mm x 2.5mm x 2.0mm.

Any help to identify the diode is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: How many pins are present and where are they placed ? A 3mm long diode with three pins -> https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/284/SM03-TP-pdf.php

Comment: There seems to be an \$\Omega\$ symbol on the device just below the *03* ?

Comment: There are only two pins, one at the top and one at the bottom (in the picture)
The symbol below the 03, I think it's the logo of the manufacturer, not an impedeance symbol.

Answer (score 1):

It will be an S1M diode from Vishay (General Semiconductor logo). SMD version of a 1N4007 diode.

https://www.vishay.com/docs/88711/s1.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much for your help...